# How to retrieve the last check-in with picture from Foursquare, knowing nothing about OAuth?

Tags: api, oauth, foursquare

I'm trying to get my last check-in with picture from the Foursquare APIs, with the following data:

- Venue name;
- Date and time of check-in;
- Picture URL;
- Check-in URL on Foursquare.com.

Fortunately or not, I am:

- Able to use jQuery's `$.getJSON` to retrieve data from public/open APIs (i.e. my last shot on Dribbble, my last song on Last.fm, or my last picture on Instagram);
- Not able to code an OAuth application, mostly because I miserably fail to understand OAuth every time I try to learn it.

Here's what I've done:

- Created an app on `foursquare.com/developers/apps`, so I now have a client ID and a client Secret;
- Tried throwing both client ID and Secrets into a `&.getJSON` request and quietly expected it to just work, like:

```
var url1 = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/checkins?client_id=XXX&client_secret=XXX",
    url2 = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/checkins?oauth_token=XXX&v=20130718"

$.getJSON(url1, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});

$.getJSON(url2, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Of course nothing works, and maybe because I'm just not getting how OAuth works and what do I have to do to authenticate my request. I tried (many times) to read OAuth documentation, but my low literacy in these matters do not help at all. Bottom line: how do I get my last check-in with picture, with my poor understanding of OAuth? Maybe a JS/PHP library could simplify this process (and I'd be much appreciated if you could suggest one), but I'd also like to understand how exactly it works.

Answer (score 2):

The users/self/checkins endpoint you're trying to use isn't possible through userless access (which is what you're trying to do with `url1`), which means, for better or worse, you'll have to use OAuth.

OAuth is all about a user giving your application permission to access this user's data on Foursquare. Through the process we describe on our [page on connecting](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth), you're able to obtain an `access_token` from us, which you need to pass with each call to our API. If this documentation is too technically dense, perhaps try using existing [OAuth library](http://oauth.net/code/) or even some up-and-coming ["OAuth-as-a-service"](https://oauth.io/) solutions. If you're getting stuck at any specific point in the auth process, feel free to email api (at) foursquare (dot) com and we'll do our best to help you through.

Comment: Thanks, @octopi. I'll definitively going to take a look at some OAuth libraries—is there any you'd recommend?

Comment: There are some on that page, but most require a server-side component. A quick search for [OAuth on GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=oauth&ref=cmdform) will return many possibilities.

If you don't have a server-side component, [OAuth.io](https://oauth.io/#/home) may be a good bet.